# Smart Array P400i Physical Drive failed after being replaced

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant, drive-failure

We have replaced the bad drives in a few HP systems (ProLiant DL360 G5), but they continue to show failed. The drives are part of RAID, and I think this might be why they are appearing as failed. The firmware/model is not the same, although they are all HP drives. Is this why they would remain in a failed state? They are new drives, so I don't think they are already bad.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the controller firmware. Are the systems up-to-date on firmware? If in question, you use the bootable [HP Firmwware DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) to bring everything up-to-date.

In addition, if you already have a running operating system on these servers, you may want to obtain the RAID status using the [HP Array Configuration Utility](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/index.html).

Sometimes, a drive will not rebuild because there could be a failing drive elsewhere in the array.

- In a RAID 1+0, errors may appear on the paired disked of the failed drive. Enough, to the point that the newly-inserted disk won't start its rebuild.
- In a RAID 5 setup, there may be unrecoverable read errors on other drives in the array, such that the new disk won't rebuild.

If either of the above are the case, the controller/rebuild status will probably be "Waiting for rebuild".

Another option, assuming these servers are healthy, may be a power cycle of the server. Sometimes that can jumpstart the rebuild on controllers with old firmware.

-- edit --

Install the [hpacucli utility for Windows Server 2008](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_55872719ce0446928c69f61a13%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) and run the following:

`ctrl all show config` 
then
 `ctrl all show config detail`

Paste the output into a pastebin or your original question.