# Proliant server will not accept new hard disks in RAID 1+0?

Tags: raid, hp, hard-drive, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a HP ProLiant DL380 G5, I have two logical drives configured with RAID. I have one logical drive RAID 1+0 with two 72 gb 10k sas 1 port spare no 376597-001.

I had one hard disk fail and ordered a replacement. The configuration utility showed error and would not rebuild the RAID. I presumed a hard disk fault and ordered a replacement again. In the mean time I put the original failed disk back in the server and this started rebuilding. Currently shows ok status however in the log I can see hardware errors.

The new disk has come and I again have the same problem of not accepting the hard disk.

I have updated the P400 controller with the latest firmware 7.24 , but still no luck.

The only difference I can see is the original drive has firmware 0103 (same as the RAID drive) and the new one has HPD2.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Logs from server

ctrl all show config

Smart Array P400 in Slot 1                (sn: PAFGK0P9VWO0UQ)

```
  array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)


  logicaldrive 1 (68.5 GB, RAID 1, Interim Recovery Mode)

  physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 73.5 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 72 GB, Failed

  array B (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)


  logicaldrive 2 (558.7 GB, RAID 5, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:5 (port 1I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:3 (port 2I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:4 (port 2I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
```

ctrl all show config detail

```
  Smart Array P400 in Slot 1
  Bus Interface: PCI
  Slot: 1
  Serial Number: PAFGK0P9VWO0UQ
  Cache Serial Number: PA82C0J9VWL8I7
  RAID 6 (ADG) Status: Disabled
  Controller Status: OK
  Hardware Revision: E
  Firmware Version: 7.24
  Rebuild Priority: Medium
  Expand Priority: Medium
  Surface Scan Delay: 15 secs
  Surface Scan Mode: Idle
  Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
  Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
  Post Prompt Timeout: 0 secs
  Cache Board Present: True
  Cache Status: OK
  Cache Status Details: A cache error was detected. Run
  more information.
  Cache Ratio: 100% Read / 0% Write
  Drive Write Cache: Disabled
  Total Cache Size: 256 MB
  Total Cache Memory Available: 208 MB
  No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
  Battery/Capacitor Count: 0
  SATA NCQ Supported: True

  Array: A
  Interface Type: SAS
  Unused Space: 0  MB
  Status: Failed Physical Drive
  Array Type: Data

  One of the drives on this array have failed or has




     Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 68.5 GB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 1
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 17594
     Strip Size: 128 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 128 KB
     Status: Interim Recovery Mode
     Caching:  Enabled
     Unique Identifier: 600508B10010503956574F305551
     Disk Name: \\.\PhysicalDrive0
     Mount Points: C:\ 68.5 GB
     Logical Drive Label: A0100539PAFGK0P9VWO0UQ0E93
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, S
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, S
     Drive Type: Data

     physicaldrive 2I:1:1
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 1
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 73.5 GB
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: 0103
     Serial Number: B379P8C006RK
     Model: HP      DG072A9B7
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown

     physicaldrive 2I:1:2
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 2
     Status: Failed
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 72 GB
     Rotational Speed: 15000
     Firmware Revision: HPD9
     Serial Number: D5A1PCA04SL01244
     Model: HP      EH0072FARUA
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown


     Array: B
     Interface Type: SAS
     Unused Space: 0  MB
     Status: OK
     Array Type: Data



     Logical Drive: 2
     Size: 558.7 GB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 5
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 65535
     Strip Size: 64 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 128 KB
     Status: OK
     Caching:  Enabled
     Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Co
     Unique Identifier: 600508B10010503956574F305551
     Disk Name: \\.\PhysicalDrive1
     Mount Points: E:\ 558.7 GB
     Logical Drive Label: AF14FD12PAFGK0P9VWO0UQD007
     Drive Type: Data

     physicaldrive 1I:1:5
     Port: 1I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 5
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPD4
     Serial Number: 3SE07QH300009923X1X3
     Model: HP      DG0300BALVP
     Current Temperature (C): 32
     Maximum Temperature (C): 45
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown

     physicaldrive 2I:1:3
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 3
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPD4
     Serial Number: 3SE0AHVH00009924P8F3
     Model: HP      DG0300BALVP
     Current Temperature (C): 34
     Maximum Temperature (C): 47
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown

     physicaldrive 2I:1:4
     Port: 2I
     Box: 1
     Bay: 4
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SAS
     Size: 300 GB
     Rotational Speed: 10000
     Firmware Revision: HPD4
     Serial Number: 3SE08NAK00009924KWD6
     Model: HP      DG0300BALVP
     Current Temperature (C): 35
     Maximum Temperature (C): 47
     PHY Count: 2
     PHY Transfer Rate: Unknown, Unknown
```

Comment: How about your controller firmware?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have a spare (replacement) drive whose size in sectors is slightly less than the original drive.

What operating system are you using? We can look at the `hpacucli` output to determine this for sure.

I will update this answer once we get more information.

Edit:

See my answer on: [Smart Array P400i Physical Drive failed after being replaced](https://serverfault.com/questions/458186/smart-array-p400i-physical-drive-failed-after-being-replaced/458190#458190) for the tool download link for Windows 2008...

I'm specifically looking for the output of `ctrl all show config`.

---

Edit:

Now that I've seen your `hpacucli` output, you're in an ***incredibly rare situation***.

```
  logicaldrive 1 (68.5 GB, RAID 1, Interim Recovery Mode)

  physicaldrive 2I:1:1 (port 2I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 73.5 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:2 (port 2I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 72 GB, Failed
```

Your original 72GB drives were actually ***larger*** than 72GB. As you can see, your healthy disk is a 73.5GB disk. HP changes disk manufacturers during the product lifetime, keeping the same spare part numbers. In this case, the replacement sent to you is a true 72GB drive. The rebuild would definitely not work.

The only thing that can fix this one is an equal or larger-size physical drive. Simply send this output to HP and ask for a 146GB disk if you're under warranty. If you're not under warranty, just get a 146GB disk and it'll rebuild as a "68.5 GB" RAID-1 member.

Also, ask for a 10k RPM 146GB disk. Your old 72GB disk is a 10k RPM (which was discontinued in that capacity LONG ago). The HP replacement is a 15k RPM drive.

Comment: The operating system is Windows server 2008 32 bit. What information do you need from the hpaculi? Is this the Array report?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Thank you, I am away from the server so will need to put the new drive back in and run the config. I am also going to update all firmware on server and see if that makes a differnce, thanks again

Comment: I have spoken to HP today, They believe we have a faulty backplane, I have been told to add the new harddrive to the exsiting RAID can this be done? I thought once a RAID is configured you could not add more drives without losing data? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can grow HP arrays without losing data. What about the output of the commands I asked about?

Comment: Have added the logs

Comment: @Leigh updated with solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this. Makes sense now it is laid out. They hae the same spare number but differnet model numbers, will order a larger drive and test again. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I'm sending this one to HP :)